Can we create am alarm in cloudwatch for rollout restart?
i tried creating the alarm in CloudWatch for rollout restart with all the default metrics and done kubectl rollout restart, the pod gets terminated and created new pod, But, i am not getting any SNS alerts, what are the possibilities to achieve this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
